# AngularJs $broadcast not working on load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

> This HTML button code is in controller:
>   **On click of a button, trying to call this function:**

```
     <button ng-click="vm.openpopup()" ng-if="!vm.data.length"
        uib-tooltip="Add Business Value Chain"
        class="btn btn-default `enter code here`ti-form-action-btn" id="add-bvc-btn">
        <em class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></em>
         Add
      </button> 

    function openpopup() {
        $scope.$broadcast('popup');
    }
```

Below is the broadcast listener code which is inside component under the same controller mentioned above:

```
$scope.$on('popup', function () {
    openModalPopup();
});
```

The button is displayed only when there is no data present.

Function call is absolutely fine, but **broadcast** works only once if there is data and if those data are deleted manually, then button gets displayed and broadcast works. But for on page load, if no data present. **Broadcast** not getting triggered.

Tried using `$rootScope.broadcast`, still no luck.

Also checking with some other answers, binded the block of code inside `$timeout`, still no results.

So this is a communication between controller and component using broadcast. How to handle this on load?

Comment: Show your code. Controllers, html etc

Comment: How are you calling the function on load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue in your case you have controlled the visibility of your button with `ng-if`, try it using `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`. In case of `ng-if` there is a chance that the template not to load. I hope that will solve your problem.

Comment: The answer looks interesting, but its not working for me. Because ill have to load the component only when data exist using `ng-if`, if i use `ng-show`. Its not loading correctly.

Comment: May be because of this, the component data getting deleted and broadcast function is not getting called. But, how is it working after load and i am manually deleting the data then?